# IRF520 max frequency

Tags: pwm, frequency

I'm having trouble supplying 300mA to an led COB using an IRF520 MOSFET as PMW, controlled with arduino nano.

What is the maximum Frequency, in which I can turn the led on and off in this setting?

In the IRF520 DATA sheet:
Turn on delay time: 8.8ns

Rise time: 30ns

Turn off delay time: 19ns

Fall time: 20ns

Is the maximum Frequency then 1/(sum of above numbers) for the IRF520?

And for the arduino timers, are they all 16MHz or does it change from pin to pin?

What is the correct calculation (please give details if different pins result in different frequencies) to determine my maximun possible operating frequency (MOSFET + arduino)?

Thanks

Comment: I have requested this question to be moved to electronics.stacexchange.

Comment: Note that to turn on and off a MOSFET at high frequency, you need to charge and discharge the gate capacitance rapidly enough which means you need a gate driver. The current source/sinking ability of an MCU pin won't cut in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nano output can only switch at 8 MHz max (except for the system clock), so the IFR520 could only change state every 125nS max. (62.5nS x 2 = 125nS, so one rising edge at time 0, followed by a falling edge 62.5nS later, then a rising edge at 125nS, and so on).

You should also look at logic level MOSFET, as th IRF520 is barely turned on with a logic level on the gate (Vgs(th) (Max) @ : 4V @ 250µA), and needs 10V to turn fully on; where as a logic level part such as AOD510/514/518 will turn fully on to conduct with a very low Rds (0.004 ohm for AOD510) at that level. (AOD514 and AOD518 are a few milliohm higher, check datasheets at Digikey.)

Comment: 1 / 8MHz = 125ns.

Comment: Thanks, clarified that.